# How do PHP mb_convert_encoding functions use in Java?

Tags: java, php

I have a base64 encode want convert to utf8 string ，use php `mb_convert_encoding` convert is normal，code by：

```
$p=base64_decode("DFknU2sALQAyADAAMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==");
echo mb_convert_encoding(substr($p, 1, 12), 'utf8', 'utf-16');
echo "\n";
```

How to convert to utf8 string in java.

```
String str = "0C5927536B002D003200300032000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
String b = hexStringToString(str); // parse hexadecimal 
String string = new String(b.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-16");
System.out.println(string); // no
```

I want result is :

```
大卫-202
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hex class in commons-codec library.

```
<dependency>     
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>     
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>     
   <version>latest</version> 
</dependency>
```

use `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;` and then:

```
String str = "0C5927536B002D003200300032000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Since in your PHP code the string is selected from byte 1 (`substr($p, 1, 12)`) you need to remove byte 1 when converting in java code. So:

```
String str = "0C5927536B002D003200300032000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
String str2 = new String(bytes, 1, 12, "UTF-16");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Comment: Thank your for you reply, I am running your code resolution. But there is garbled. The result is:  Y'Sk-202

Comment: I use php mb_convert_encoding convert is normal.

Comment: I see! It seems your output is UTF-16 and when convert by Java print something different. However, when use `String str = "e5a4a7e58dab2d323032";` it's work. Let me check.

Comment: Hexadecimal maybe different. ```String str = "0C5927536B002D003200300032000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; `` `is my source data. please check my code. https://www.online-java.com/qm6hy95HU4

Comment: No, it's OK. print `print($p . "\n");` in php and see results. Same as ` Y'Sk-202`.

Comment: Ok ,  thank you very much, the ```print(mb_convert_encoding(substr($p, 1, 12), 'utf-8', 'utf-16') . "\n"); ```is my want see results;

Comment: There was a trick. see edited post.

Comment: I use your code, but still appear garbled. 
```
 String hex2 ="26003000314E2D5C715317FFFFFF8DFFFFFFEF3001FFFFFF91FFFFFFD15C716C5FFFFFFF8DFFFFFFEF4EFFFFFFA46C47FFFFFF8DFFFFFFEF53FFFFFFE30061003000300031000000";
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hex2.toCharArray());
String str2 = new String(bytes, 1, 41, "UTF-16");
System.out.println(str2);
```
Please help me check it . thank you. @Majid Hajibaba

Comment: Let me check it tomorrow. What's your desired output?